What is the locus of $z_3 = \frac{z_1}{z_2}$ as the real part of $z_2$ varies?
Question:
Let $z_1 = a + bi$ and $z_2 = c + di$. Determine the locus of $z_3 = \frac{z_1}{z_2}$ as $c$ varies.
My working so far:
I've done this:
$$
z_3 = \frac{z_1}{z_2} = \frac{a + bi}{c + di} = \frac{(a + bi)(c - di)}{(c + di)(c - di)} = \frac{(a + bi)(c - di)}{c^2 + d^2}
$$ and have gotten: $$ \text{Re}(z_3)= \frac{ac + bd}{c^2 + d^2}, \; \text{Im}(z_3) = \frac{bc - ad}{c^2 + d^2}$$
and
$$ x=\frac{ac + bd}{c^2 + d^2}, \; y = \frac{bc - ad}{c^2 + d^2} $$
Don't know how to proceed, I'm pretty sure I need to get an equation which has all the variables but $c$ in it, but I can't figure out how to get there.


How does $x(c)=\dfrac{ac+bd}{c^2+d^2}, y(c)=\dfrac{bc-ad}{c^2+d^2}$ form on the x-y plane?

Just seeing that the numerators have the form of Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity($(ac+bd)^2+(bc-ad)^2=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$), I strongly believed that the form is the “circle.”
\begin{align}
& \text{let } (x-k)^2+(y-l)^2=r^2. \\
\Rightarrow \; & (ac+bd-(c^2+d^2)k)^2+(bc-ad-(c^2+d^2)k)^2=(c^2+d^2)^2r^2. \\
& \vdots \\
&\text{With some calculations, we get:} \\
& k=\dfrac{b}{2d}, l=-\dfrac{a}{2d}, r^2=\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{4d^2}. \\
\therefore \; & \left( x-\dfrac{b}{2d} \right)^2+\left( y + \dfrac{a}{2d} \right)^2=\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{4d^2}.
\end{align}
